# setting twig value depending on current device

Tags: twig

Using bootstrap( 3.3.6.) and twig( 1.24.0 ) is there is a way to set different value to some twig variable, depending on
current device?
  I suppose something like

```
<div class="visible-xs">{% set images_in_1_row = 1 %}</div>
<div class="visible-sm">{% set images_in_1_row = 2 %}</div>
<div class="visible-md">{% set images_in_1_row = 3 %}</div>
<div class="visible-lg">{% set images_in_1_row = 4 %}</div>
```

and if current device is ipad, I suppose images_in_1_row has value "2", but not "4"...

Thanks!

Comment: How would Twig know if you are using an iPad or something else?

Comment: This can't be done with twig. Twig is compiled into PHP and PHP is interpreted serverside. What you need to do is use mediaqueries to change how many images there can be in one row.

Comment: Could, you, please, give refs to examples of using of mediaqueries ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a small snippet how you should do this with `CSS`:

```css
   * {
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
   }
   #container {
    width : 1000px;
    background : #DFF2BF;
    min-height : 100vh;
    border-left : 1px solid #4f8a10;
    border-right : 1px solid #4f8a10;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }
   .clear {
    clear : both;
   }
   ul {
    list-style : none;
    padding : 25px;
   }
   
   ul li {
    width :300px;
    margin : 0 25px 25px 0;
    float : left;
   }
   ul li img {
    width: 100%;
   }
   ul li:nth-of-type(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
   }
   @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 999px) {
    #container {
     width : 768px;
    }
    ul li {
     width: 345px;
    }
    ul li:nth-of-type(2n) {
     margin-right: 0;
    }
    ul li:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
     margin-right : 25px;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    #container {
     width : 480px;
    }
    ul li {
     width : 430px;
     margin-right 0;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    #container {
     width : 320px;
    }
    ul li {
     width : 280px;
     margin-right 0;
    }
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
      <title>Mediaqueries Gallery</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <ul>
    <li><img src="http://www.bekijksite.be/test/placeholder.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.bekijksite.be/test/placeholder.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.bekijksite.be/test/placeholder.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.bekijksite.be/test/placeholder.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.bekijksite.be/test/placeholder.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.bekijksite.be/test/placeholder.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.bekijksite.be/test/placeholder.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.bekijksite.be/test/placeholder.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.bekijksite.be/test/placeholder.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.bekijksite.be/test/placeholder.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.bekijksite.be/test/placeholder.png" /></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```